# My PC turns on by itself exactly at the 10 minute mark at every hour

Tags: windows, windows-10, wake-up, powercfg

A little bit of history, my PC was turned off for around 1 month, until recently. I turned it on just to update windows 10. After a few days, my PC turns on by itself, at every hour at the 10 minute mark.

At first I thought it was something related to electricity and/or PSU problems, but it is very consistent, at the 10 minute mark, it turns itself on. It looks like, it only turns on during day time. After 2 am, the PC doesn't turn on by itself.

Every time my PC has turned on, I try to see what caused it to turn in Event viewer, but `Power troubleshooter` entry has wake source as `Unkown`, and `powercfg` doesn't provide any meaningful information.

I have tested leaving my PC sleeping, and it doesn't wake up. It stays asleep. It only turns on when it is shutdown.

This is a list of what I have tried but hasn't worked:

- Disabled automatic maintenance in Security Maintenance options
- Disabled all devices that can turn on PC with powercfg
- Disabled wake up timers options in Power options
- Windows 10 is up to date and I did a DISM and SFC. Everything is OK
- Updated motherboard BIOS
- I made sure motherboard power on options are disabled (wake up LAN, etc.)
- Disabled windows update schedule to wake up PC (through regedit)
- Disabled all tasks that have the option to wake up PC in task scheduler
- Disabled `Turn on fast startup` in Power options

Does anyone have any idea of what to try next? I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Have you tried the command `powercfg /lastwake`. Besides that a multiple socket outlet with a switch is a good way to save power and prevent any wake up.

Comment: @Robert yes, I have. No information of what caused the wake up.

Comment: @Robert To make sure the PC stays turned off I have been switching off the PSU. It is just a bummer, something broke and I have no idea what it is

Comment: Does it happen if you shutdown *after booting in Safe mode*?

Comment: @harrymc that would have been a good idea to test. Fortunately for me I have found the culprit. Although I don't know exactly why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the cause. It was the wifi antenna that was attached to the motherboard.

While I was deattaching the wifi antenna, the PC turned on by itself. I turned it off again and hasn't turned on again since.

It makes me think some wires or pins were touching and they were the actual culprits but it doesn't explain why at the 10 minute mark...